# Select an input type text and page will slide instead of clicking link

Tags: jquery, forms, slider

Okay so I have this website where I have a form on the sidebar but there's not enough space for the whole thing. I've decided to use this jQuery pageslide http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-pageslide/ but instead of clicking the link to activate the pageslide, I want to activate it when user clicks on the visible input type text box.

Is this possible? My site is located at http://www.publicis-malaysia.com/thegladesv2

Comment: @alex wouldn't want people to start googling and go to the page as it's still in a staging process :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample on the pageslide site this should be easy: note the selector is changed to `input[type=text]`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type=text]').pageSlide({
            width: "300px"
        });
    });
</script>
```

You might want the selector to be `$('#sidebar input[type=text]')`